# NodeJS, how to handle image uploading with MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I would like to know what is the best way to handle image uploading and saving the reference to the database. What I'm mostly interested is what order do you do the process in?

Should you upload the images first in the front-end (say Cloudinary), and then call the API with result links to the images and save it to the database?

Or should you upload the images to the server first, and upload them from the back-end and save the reference afterwards?

OR, should you do the image uploading after you save the record in the database and then update it once the images were uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the resources, timeline, and number of images you need to upload daily.

So basically if you have very few images to upload then you can upload that image to your server then upload it to any cloud storage(s3, Cloudinary,..) you are using. As this will be very easy to implement(you can find code snippet over the internet) and you can securely maintain your secret keys/credential to your cloud platform on the server side.

But, according to me best way of doing this will be something like this. I am taking user registration as an example

1. Make server call to get a temporary credential to upload files on the cloud(Generally, all the providers give this functionality i.e. STS/Signed URL in AWS).
2. The user will fill up the form and select the image on the client side. When the user clicks the submit button make one call to save the user in the database and start upload with credentials. If possible keep a predictable path for upload. Like for user upload /users/:userId or something like that. this highly depends on your use case.
3. Now when upload finishes make a server call for acknowledgment and store some flag in the database.

**Now advantages of this approach are:**

1. You are completely offloading your server from handling file operations which are pretty heavy and I/O blocking and you are distributing that load to all clients.
2. If you want to post process the files after upload you can easily integrate this with serverless platforms and do that on there and again offload that.
3. You can easily provide retry mechanism to your users in case of file upload fails but they won't need to refill the data, just upload the image/file again
4. You don't need to expose the URL directly to the client for file upload as you are using temporary Creds.

Answer (score 0):

If the significance of the images in your app is high then ideally, you should not complete the transaction until the image is saved. The approach should be to create an object in your code which you will eventually insert into mongodb, start upload of image to cloud and then add the link to this object. Finally then insert this object into mongodb in one go. Do not make repeated calls. Anything before that, raise an error and catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

You can have many answers,

if you are working with big files greater than 16mb please go with gridfs and multer,

( changing the images to a different format and save them to mongoDB)

If your files are actually less than 16 mb, please try using this Converter that changes the image of format jpeg / png to a format of saving to mongodb, and you can see this as an easy alternative for gridfs ,

[please check this github repo for more details..](https://github.com/saran-surya/Mongo-Image-Converter)